# Had Mark Knopfler written some more rock songs after Dire Straits?

Tags: rock, guitar

I love Mark Knopfler's guitar playing such that I would not turn off his playing but neither deliberately listen to him. So I do not really follow his career path.

Just out of curiosity: had he ever written some "hit" **rock** songs after Dire Straits ([*Sultans of Swing*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fAQhSRLQnM) or [*Money for Nothing*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRDgihVDEko), among others)?

I am under the impression that he favors more of soft, tender love songs after Dire Straits.

Answer (score 2):

He's continued to write songs to this day in his solo career. He hasn't had as much main stream success, but he does continue to write and he has many solo albums currently out:

- Golden Heart (1996)
- Sailing to Philadelphia (2000)
- The Ragpicker's Dream (2002)
- Shangri-La (2004)
- One Take Radio Sessions (2005)
- Kill to Get Crimson (2007)
- Get Lucky (2009)
- Privateering (2012)
- Tracker (2015)

For indiviual song succues, one note is the song [Darling Pretty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCMnxue38Gc) which peaked at 33 on the UK singles chart and was on the soundtrack of the movie *Twister*.

Comment: Hey thanks. How about rock songs? In fact, rock songs are the originally requirement. I guess I know he still has activities!

Comment: *Darling Pretty* still sounds slow paced, ballad...

Comment: Like it or not, all of his albums are considered rock. Roots rock and folk rock specifically.  Rock is a very broad category of music.

Comment: Let us let along the academic classification. Let us use intuition instead. I used "Sultans of Swing" as a signal to narrow down what I was after. Like, if one calls "Sultans of Swing" a rock song then she would not deem "Romeo and Julie" as the same "category", right? It is in this sense I was raising the question. One can of course collect a song into the set of pop rock; however, this is not substantial in terms of addressing the current question. Thanks for your efforts however.